# Reading a string is not going properly

Tags: c, string, malloc, char

Hey guys, i'm working on a program that gets a postfix expression and calculates it..

I have two functions:

1. Converts infix to postfix
2. Calculate the postfix

When I try small expressions, like 1+1 or (1+1)*1, it works fine
but when i use all the operands I get something nasty,

Here is the example:
2*2/2+1-1
gets something like:
222/*11-+T_CHECKÖÐ7?█Ã

If you see, the expression is right until the 'T'

I believe it's some parameter mistake, so i'll put the header and return values here

1st)

```
char* convert(char *infix);
char *post = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*tamP);
return post;
```

2nd)

```
int evaluate(char *postfix)
while (*postfix != '\0')
return result;
```

Caller)

```
char* post = convert(infix);
result = evaluate(post);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you should also mention the definition of convert(char*).

Comment: This isn't enough info to say for sure, but if there's "garbage" at the end of your string, double check that your code always puts a '\0' character at the end after building it.

Comment: Those code snippets are incomplete: There's no parsing or conversion code. What are `tamP` and `result`? How are you reading in the string? How are you writing the result string? Any answers you get will just be guesses until you post something more complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you are not adding the '\0' character at the end of 'post' (after the last sensible character) in the convert(char*) function. That's one reason I can think of.
Try setting the complete string to '\0' before you do anything with it:

```
memset(post, 0, tamP);
```

should do.

Comment: It almost did the thing, but you lead me on the right question, i don't know why, but when the stack finished putting the operands, on the last one the string got those wierld stuff, then i put an '\0' when the stack finishes putting the operands and worked!  thks

Answer (score 4):

That kind of weird string looks more like a buffer overflow error. You are likely overwriting the null-terminator, so when the string is printed (or later used), it keeps going until it finds one, examining random program memory until it gets there.

Check that all of your string manipulations are correct.